# Append arrays to array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I would like to know, what is the correct way to append arrays to array and then access the one of them at a time using their locations?

For example, I have a loop which will outputs an array and i want to append it to an array and then access it as next input for the loop.

```
array = [[1 2 3],
         [3 4 5],
         [5 6 4]]
```

Code Layout:

```py
import numpy as np

array = []
i = 0

data = pd.read_csv("File")
array = np.append(array, data)

while True:
     d = array[:, i]           #access all the elements of the column (represent as an array)
     """
     Perform operation
     """
     np.append(array, result)        #result is an array type (1D)
     i += 1

     if result.size == 0
         break;
```

What is the best function to execute such operation?

## Update

One way to add an array to the array is using `stacking process`. Depending on preference of stacking `row-wise` or `col-wise`, one may use `np.vstack()` or `np.hstack()` respectively.
Note: The NumPy arrays are restricted to regular array size, any irregularities in the spread will not be compatible.

Comment: Don't attempt to use `np.append` as a substitute (or in the manner of) a list append.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for the response, I tried `stacking process` like `hstack` or `vstack` and it works.

Comment: @hpaulj however i am still looking for an option which doesn't have restriction on the array size. (for example - stacking irregular arrays together).

Comment: For arrays of differing sizes just keep them in a list.  What are you trying to do with them that requires multidimensional access?